# Try/catch blocks inside constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, exception, typeinitializer

Is it a bad programming practice to have try/catch blocks inside constructors? Or does it make no difference as long as our programs handle typeinitializer exceptions gracefully.

In C# if there are any exceptions inside a constructor the framework always throws typeinitilizer exceptions.

Thanks,
Shamika

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`System.TypeInitializationException` is thrown when a *static* constructor throws an exception, not on an instance constructor. Exceptions are thrown normally in instance constructors.

That aside, there's nothing "wrong" with it any more than it is anywhere else; handle exceptions that you can properly recover from, and allow those that you can't to bubble up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on System.TypeInitializationException and yes, in my case it's a static constructor indeed.

Comment: @Shamika: Nonetheless, the same answer applies; if you can recover from the exception, then catch it. If you can't, then don't. Also note that exceptions encountered in static member initialization can't be caught (they will throw a `TypeInitializationException`).

Comment: question, is it better to use a try catch surrounding the call to the constructor or inside the constructor?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou As with exceptions in general, you should catch an exception only when you can *handle* the exception (unless you rethrow). If your constructor can complete and give you a valid object in the event of that exception, then you should have the try-catch in the constructor. If not, then don't put it in there unless you rethrow it.